# How to find if an image is a gradient image?

Tags: python, image-processing, gradient

I am working on piece of code that takes an image file (PNG/JPG) as an input and does the following:

- Detects colors if the image is consisting of solid colors. Allowing the end user to replace those colors.
- In case of gradients, it changes the color to a solid black.

We are using Python and I am open to any libraries/APIs that can help as well

Can anyone help with what best can be done?

To identify if an uploaded image is a gradient or not, we have tried Laplacian filter for color and edge detection and Sobel for color and edge detection and played around with thresholds to detect gradients but it is not as accurate as it should be.

Comment: How do you define "a gradient image"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.